# Select oracle date column using C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, date

I am trying to select data from my Oracle database BY DATE using C#. However I am always getting an empty data set although the same query string works just fine in Oracle SQL Developer

```
String Query = "Select position_date from position";
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(Query, ocon); 
adapter.Fill(ds, "table"); //where ds is a dataset 
PrintDataSet(ds);
```

returns

```
3/8/2011 12:00:00 AM.... and more
```

However, when I change my query to below, then there is no output!

```
String Query = "Select position_date from position 
where to_char(position_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') = '05-17-2012'"
```

This query works fine in oracle sql developer. I've also tried trunc(sysdate) but nothing seems to work! :(

Comment: Bit rusty, but try this - "select * from position where position_date = to_date('05-17-2012', 'mm-dd-yyyy')"

Comment: Well `3/8/2011` is a completely different day than `05-17-2012`. It does make sense to me that you are not getting anything back. And you should not convert the date to a string but the string to a date. Using `position_date = to_date('05-17-2012', 'mm-dd-yyyy')` will enable Oracle to use an index on position_date.

Comment: @horse, That may be so, but it is not an equivalent query. The posted query should get everything on 5/17/12, your query gets you everything on 5/17/12 *at midnight*. You probably meant TRUNC(position_date) = to_date('05-17-2012', 'mm-dd-yyyy')

Comment: What does 'query works fine in oracle sql developer' mean? Is it returning any data?

Comment: @DCookie: yes of course you are right.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura, Yes. the query in the second strings returns the correct data, but empty when used in c#

Thanks everyone for the response, i will try using to_date() instead and see if it works! :)

Comment: What is the default date format on your system?  Perhaps '05-17-2012' is not being interpreted correctly.  If so, DCookie's solution will fix this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from position where trunc(position_date) = to_date('05-17-2012', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates have no time component (and if that is so then guarantee it with a check constraint), then:

```
Select position_date
from   position 
where  position_date = date '2012-05-17'
```

Otherwise:

```
Select position_date
from   position 
where  position_date >= date '2012-05-17' and 
       position_date <  date '2012-05-17' + 1
```

Comment: String Query = "Select position_date from position pos where pos.position_date >= date '2012-05-17' and pos.position_date < date '2012-05-17' + 1 and  rownum < 11";

This does not return anything when used in C#, but returns 10 rows in Oracle sql developer...